# Is it possible to show a Facebook app as a Page Tab on mobile devices?

Tags: iphone, facebook, mobile, facebook-page

For example, the following URL shows the app in a tab:

https://www.facebook.com/just.to.get.a.rep?sk=app_203403406338325

But when on a mobile device it redirects to the mobile site and does not show the tab or even have a link to it:

https://m.facebook.com/just.to.get.a.rep?sk=app_203403406338325

I even have the application tab set as the Default Landing Tab for this page, but cannot get the pap to show for the page. Is there another format we need to develop for the App to support mobile? Ideally we would like to show the tab on iPhone app and other mobile viewing.

Comment: On that external page, is there any way to force users to Like the facebook page?

Comment: You can't ever force users to like a page, but you can certainly add a Like button on an external page.

Comment: You can work around the problem as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15860533/121285

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's not currently any way to see App-provided Page tabs on the m.facebook.com site

[Mobile](https://developers.facebook.com/mobile/) web apps are supported, but they're not tied to the Page and need to be manually linked-to or bookmarked, the tab functionality simply doesn't exist now.

Comment: Is Facebook saying if these might be included in the future? I was at a presentation from a Facebook rep this weekend where he said that 50% of users are accessing via mobile...

Comment: I'm not aware of any plans to change how this works (but don't want to rule it out either). 
If we have something to announce it will likely appear on either the Roadmap ( https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap ) or Developer Blog ( https://developers.facebook.com/blog/ )

Comment: Note to disappointed SO'ers: Don't dismay, check @CBroe's solution below.  It may not work for your situation, but as it turns out, it's exactly what we needed!  Good luck!

Answer (score 49):

If you're in control of the link the user clicks on to reach your fanpage/pagetab-combination, then try adding a GET parameter ref=ts

h++ps://www.facebook.com/just.to.get.a.rep?sk=app_203403406338325&**ref=ts**

Apparently this prevents the redirect to the mobile version of facebook.

Comment: Works as advertised! Thank you. I was getting 404, but simply adding ref=ts in my redirect URLs (I force users to use my app as a page tab) fixed it!

Comment: Unfortunately this causes the page to error if the URL is accessed from inside the Facebook mobile app.

Comment: url has a typo. Please fix it. Shouldn't it be 'http'.

Comment: i believe that´s intentional, so it does not create a link

Comment: @LysanderGray: Did you find a workaround for this?  For years, the solution provided by CBroe seemed to work.  However, now I've noticed the links don't work from the FB mobile app.  Maybe this is the way it was before and I just didn't notice it?  Not sure...

Comment: For those who are curious, we solved this by using a URL on our server (e.g. `https://example.com/app.html?page=111&app=222`) instead of the actual Facebook app URL.  The code on our system detects if the user is on desktop or mobile.  If on desktop, it simply forwards the request to the Facebook app URL.  If on mobile, it serves up the app directly to the browser (without any surrounding Facebook chrome).  This solution has worked very well for our needs.  (Note that we also wrap the link in a `http://goo.gl` link shortener link to hide our domain a bit from the end user.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can develop application functions such as [app authorisation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) but sadly no, you can't display standard iFramed tab apps, I suspect this is because of slow 3G data speeds and the fact that Facebook wouldn't want the mobile experience being any slower than it already is (dependent on external hosting etc).

Many of my larger clients are begging for it. The only workaround I use is to build an external page with the same content used in the iFrame - then you can direct users to the tab or mobile users to an external link.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.facebook.com/pagename/app_000000000000000?ref=page_internal

as of now ref=page_internal is working as a work around.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect Mobile users to a specific mobile website, and have desktop users redirected to your page tab app.

Detailed instructions for doing this are available here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15860533/121285