# How to make and link to a Facebook tab page app, for both mobile AND web?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, mobile, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to show a Facebook app as a Page Tab on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220579/is-it-possible-to-show-a-facebook-app-as-a-page-tab-on-mobile-devices)

I want to post a link on my fan wall which will take users, both mobile and web based, to an app I've developed, but at the moment, for mobile users it simply takes them to my WALL for the fan page despite setting up a "mobile web" url for it.

Similar question was asked here:

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7220579/is-it-possible-to-show-a-facebook-app-as-a-page-tab-on-mobile-devices

But it doesn't fully answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it does, **Fan Page Tabs are not available on the mobile version of Facebook**.

The only way you could got is to set up a gateway page on your server that checks if the user is on a desktop pc or mobile device, if it's a desktop -> redirect to the usual tab. If it's a mobile device redirect somewhere else where the same content is served, just without Facebook. You then share this link on your wall.