# Is there a work around solution for displaying Facebook App tabs on mobile device?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

At the moment when you send a Facebook tab URL link to a mobile device you get the following response 'The page you requested was not found' - does anyone know of a workout solution - maybe utilising a fb mobile app that would allow the display of page tab on mobile devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to provide App Canvas URL to show mobile version of the app to the users who use mobile devices instead of the Page Tab URL. Note that if an user access to the App Canvas URL in a mobile device, the user will see the content of the 'Mobile Web URL' in the facebook app setting, while an user access to the App Canvas URL in a desktop browser, the user will se the content of the "App Canvas URL."

1. When an user access to the App Canvas URL in a desktop browser, just redirect to the page tab url
2. When an user access to the App Canvas URL in a mobile device, Facebook will redirect the user to the Mobile Web URL, just serve mobile version of the app in Mobile Web URL.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - i have a page tab URL which is on my hosted domain site - if I put this URL in the mobile app setting - then they will be directed to my web content (which won't be connected to a Facebook tab) If I put the app.facebook/xxx for the mobile URL then this also won't work as they will say that splash is misconfigured.

Answer (score 1):

try this (from here: [Is it possible to show a Facebook app as a Page Tab on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220579/is-it-possible-to-show-a-facebook-app-as-a-page-tab-on-mobile-devices))

```
https://www.facebook.com/fbpageurlname?sk=app_123403406338325&ref=ts
```

adding &ref=ts to the end of the url stops the page tab redirecting to the mobile version of the site.

also, remember to use `/fbpageurlname?sk=app_APPID` and not `/fbpageurlname/app_APPID`

otherwise you'll get a page not found error when you add the &ref=ts to the end of the url

Comment: You can use ?ref=ts instead of &ref=ts, if you want to stick to /fbpageurlname/app_APPID...