# Page tab application to run in smartphones

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook Tab application that I installed on my Page is not even viewable on smartphones.What are the different ways so that I can make them viewable?Is facebook doing something for it?
I can't paste the web link (URL) to my app as wall post.That's cheap.
Any other suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220579/is-it-possible-to-show-a-facebook-app-as-a-page-tab-on-mobile-devices), there is no way to view page tabs with apps on mobile Facebook website, you can only create mobile version of your app and user will be redirected to it when accessing from mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't support page tab application on smartphones. So you need to make mobile application. However you can make page tab application and mobile application by same program.

https://shindan-social.herokuapp.com/sss2.salesforce.com/sites

I think this is helpful for developing your app. You know Facebook page use POST method by fetching page from your server. You can distinguish which browser user use from POST or GET methods and user-agent.