# Facebook app development on mobile devices

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I've created a company page on Facebook to which I've added some iframe apps that we've developed. These work great on PC and I can see the tabs to these apps under the cover image. All well and good.

In the development area I've entered a **Mobile Site URL** under the Mobile Web section, but when I view the Facebook page on a mobile phone, there is no sign of a link (like the tabs on the desktop version). Should there be some kind of link on the mobile version or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question.

Seems this is not possible.

[Is it possible to show a Facebook app as a Page Tab on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220579/is-it-possible-to-show-a-facebook-app-as-a-page-tab-on-mobile-devices)

Comment: This might help achieve what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15860533/121285