# Show a specific facebook page in desktop mode on a mobile device

Tags: facebook, mobile-safari

On mobile devices, I can force facebook to show the desktop main screen with

```
https://www.facebook.com/home.php
```

on the other hand there are specific pages like this famous one

```
https://www.facebook.com/4/
```

Is there a way to combine those and showing a specific facebook page on a mobile device (iPhone) in desktop mode? Something like

```
https://www.facebook.com/home.php?showme=/4/
```

or

```
https://www.facebook.com/4/?mode=desktop
```

The last two urls don't work. They're here to illistrate what I'm searching for.

Yes. I'm aware that Safari on iOS allows the user to force Safari to show the Desktop Sit and this works with facebook. But I'm looking for a solution without forcing the user doing this each time.

Comment: You can try if parameter `ref=ts` still works, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10833366/1427878

Comment: I tested, it doesn't work for me. Also `ref=internal` as suggested as a different answer to the same question doesn't work for me.

Comment: Well, then probably Facebook has closed all those “loopholes” by now.

Comment: thanks anyways :-)